# the subproject example give me an error the Scenario .Ned file not found

Tags: veins

I am trying to work on the subproject example that is exist in the veins. But it give me an error the Scenario .Ned file not found.
If there any one can help me please type the steps to me how I can solve this problem
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you imported the subproject as a "project" in the IDE or are you working in the "subprojects" folder of Veins (in the IDE)?

Answer (score 0):

The proper method to use the subprojects in veins is already explained. Please take a look at
[Error when building veins_inet subproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385671/error-when-building-veins-inet-subproject)